# Powershell Try catch write errors to an external txt file

Tags: powershell, debugging, office365, exchange-server

I have a PowerShell script to disable email forwarding in Office 365 using a CSV file. I want to catch all errors to an external Txt file.
Here's my code:

```
$Groups |
ForEach-Object {
    $PrimarySmtpAddress = $_.PrimarySmtpAddress
    try {
        # disable Mail forwarding
        Set-Mailbox -Identity $PrimarySmtpAddress -ForwardingSmtpAddress $Null 
    }
    Catch {
        $PrimarySmtpAddress  | Out-File $logfile -Append
    }
}
```

but it doesn't catch errors.

Is there any instruction to catch errors to an external file?

Any solution will be helpful.

Comment: `Write-Host` bypasses the pipeline. If you must, use `Out-Default`, or just pipe the string to then `Out-File` cmdlet. If the `Set-Mailbox` isn't throwing the error, you have an additional issue that needs to be investigated in more depth.

Comment: A `Try/Catch` block only works on terminating errors, so if the cmdlet throws an error, but just moves on this won't work. You may need to add `-ErrorAction Stop` to your `Set-Mailbox` cmdlet. Also, as mentioned by Jeff Zeitlin,  the `Write-Host` cmdlet does not pass things down the pipeline. Add a new line to your `Catch` block to output the info to your text file.

Comment: i've removed Write-Host and still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Jeff Zeitlin's and TheMadTechnician's comments, changes noted in inline comments:

```
$Groups | ForEach-Object {
    $PrimarySmtpAddress = $_.PrimarySmtpAddress
    Try {
        # disable Mail forwarding
        #Added ErrorAction Stop to cause errors to be terminating
        Set-Mailbox -Identity $PrimarySmtpAddress -ForwardingSmtpAddress $Null -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    Catch {
        #Removed Write-Host as Write-Host writes to the host, not down the pipeline, Write-Output would also work
        "$PrimarySmtpAddress" | Out-File $logfile -Append
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    #or $ErrorMessage= $Error[0].Exception.Message
    if($ErrorMessage -ne $null) {
        ... Your custom code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Exchange Online (a.k.a O365) does not honor the thrown error for your catch statement to work. We have had to set

```
$global:ErrorActionPreference=Stop
```

to get the error object to return

Note: We implemented this using the following at beginning of function

```
$saved=$global:ErrorActionPreference
$global:ErrorActionPreference=Stop
```

and reverted the setting at the end of the function using

```
$global:ErrorActionPreference=$saved
```